# How to combine the code of two array queries in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I need to combine two queries that are both inside arrayformulas so that I just have one query:

I've tried using Union

**First Code:**

```
 = ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({MID(Sheet1!B1:B, 8, 5), Sheet1!A1:AS}, 
 "select count(Col13) 
 where Col13>=0 
 group by Col1 
 label count(Col13)'Winners #'"))
```

**Second Code:**

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({MID(Sheet1!B1:B, 8, 5), Sheet1!A1:AS}, 
"select count(Col13) 
where Col13<=0 
group by Col1 
label count(Col13)'Losers #'"))
```

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential data).

Comment: @Tedinoz: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUwx0eh20nBQpISg7OQ0il-U0s8wNDHuLt2zlheBdRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tedinoz the "grouping project" tab has the data, "Sheet 1" has the two queries I'm trying to combine, and "Sheet 2" has the dates sorted but I would also like to know how to add more selections to that query such as 'count(Col3)' but this requires adding more columns. If you know how to do that, that would be great. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({
 QUERY({MONTH(MID('grouping project'!A2:A, 8, 3)&1)&"♦"&
              MID('grouping project'!A2:A, 8, 5), 'grouping project'!A2:AO}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col3),'Winners #'
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col3 >= 0 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col3)'','Winners #'''", 0);
 QUERY({MONTH(MID('grouping project'!A2:A, 8, 3)&1)&"♦"&
              MID('grouping project'!A2:A, 8, 5), 'grouping project'!A2:AO}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col3),'Loosers #'
  where Col3 <= 0 
    and Col1 is not null
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col3)'','Loosers #'''", 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2)
  group by Col1
  pivot Col3
  label Col1'Week ending'", 0)), "^.+♦", ), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you SO much. I'm new to SQL...anyway you could describe the code?

Comment: @ajg basically, both of your queries are put under each other and to each is assigned "fake" column (either winners or losers). then its put as a whole under query again where we use fake sum so we could pivot it based on the fake win/lose column. regex is there just to fix chronology of column A

Comment: A work of art - where does one start?
In the formula for `MONTH`, would you explain the purpose of `&1`?
In the second `MID`, what is the purpose of `&"♦"&` to join the `MONTH` value with the `Mid` value?
In the first `SELECT` statement, what is the significance of `'Winners #'` after the count statement? I note a label is added later in the SELECT.

Comment: in order to convert month names eg. Jan, Feb, etc to numbers you need: `=MONTH("Jan"&1)` hence the `MONTH` and `&1`. then we join it with unique symbol ♦ (could be whatever symbol ♪♫♥♣♠♂♀...) so stuff in column A would look like: `01♦Jan11`, `01♦Jan18`, `01♦Jan25`, `02♦Feb01`, `03♦Mar03`, etc. this way column A can be nicely sorted chronologically and after its sorted the extra stuff is removed by regex formula `"^.+♦"` - which translates as "remove everything from start till unique symbol ♦ including unique symbol itself"

Comment: as for the query... actually label is explicitly removed `'Winners #'''` - means empty label. where `'Winners #'` under `select` means that we create a fake column. example: paste this formula in some cell to see whats going on - `=QUERY({"value 1", "value A"; "value 2", "value B"}, "select Col1,Col2,'fake column' label 'fake column'''")` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnYHa.png

Comment: @player0 could you show me how to combine the two queries on Sheet 3 that I just added?

Comment: @Tedinoz I apologize - I forgot to tag you in previous comments so not sure if it reached you. if so then I apologize for interruption.

Comment: @player0 Appreciate your explanations.

Comment: @player0 how do I change the order of the columns after the pivot? Right now it's alphabetical but I'd like it to be "picks #, return #, winners #"